# What is package in the beginning of a java document?

Tags: java, android

I found some useful samples in github about searchable dictionary.

Every java file in the searchable dictionary folder starts with

```
package com.example.android.searchabledict;
```

What does `package` do and how should I use it?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://google.com) website?

Comment: Please make your own research before posting a question on SO... [First Google search link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package)

Answer (score 0):

Package objects contain version information about the implementation and specification of a Java package.Package it imports the class or set of class.The package are stored in the manifest file.
For more details please go through the link .https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Package.html